# Marquee text alignment is not proper

Tags: html, css

Below is my code for Marquee ,when marquee stops rolling `Alexander the Great: THE GREATEST` this text get hidden , I tried `text align` property but that is not working , what do i do so that text get display same after marquee as it is displaying before marquee roll?

**when marquee starts**

[image: start of marquee]

**when marquee stops**

[image: stop of marquee]

```
<div class="video-header" style="margin-left:50px;">
<div class="span8" style="padding-left: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px; display:block; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap; color:#353535; overflow:hidden; width:100%;font-size:15px;">
<?php echo ' <marquee LOOP=1 BEHAVIOR=SLIDE>'
   .  stripslashes(_cut($video->title, 280)); ?> - <?php echo time_ago($video->date) . '</marquee>' ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to either reduce the font-size or increase the width of div to accommodate it.

Comment: @ I can't increase width nor either can reduce font size , its client requirement whatever size are there , i have to manage rolling functionality in that only

Comment: Give me the output link

Comment: @ManojKumar I m running it on localhost